# Withdrawing funds from the contract creation address if the contract creation fails

Tags: remix, withdrawal

Would like to withdraw funds from smart contract back to Meta Mask wallet, but not sure how. Contract address: 0x9766a87A6A56F8386463ba41a36065E59d855BCB Any advice? Thank you

Comment: I also made a contract, with a script, but it seems I lost my eth via that, in the script there wasn't any reroutes but instead of depositing it into the "contract" it went to a wallet I didn't set... Is there any way to recover this?

Answer (score 0):

The contract creation to this address has failed.

[image]

[image]

I do not believe it is possible to withdraw the funds.